# Changing the CopyRight Notification Year from 2019 to 2020 in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, database, api

I tried out Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Design (left menu) -> Footer ->  Copyright but it is not changing the Year from 2019 to 2020....Any correct solution  ...Reply back to this Question as soon as possible....

[image]

Comment: Did you check phtml file and also it could be possible that someone adds text based on the store so please check that and after that please clear the cache.

Comment: Flush the cache and check in the private window.

Comment: I have flushed the Cache as well as

Comment: turn on template hints and check the frontend to check for a custom footer template.